# NO VALIDA CAMPO API CON DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, djangorestframework

estoy tratando de validar un campo al momento de ingresar valores por la API de django, no logro realizar esta validación: que en precio no ingresen 0, y no se repita el campo titulo.

Model

```
class Producto(models.Model):
productoName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
productoDescription = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
productoPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
productoImage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
# create_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
def __str__ (self):
    return self.productoName
```

Serializador:

```
class ProductoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Producto
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ('created_at',)

def validate_title(self, data):
    try:
        # Intenta crear una instancia temporal de Task para verificar la unicidad del título.
        Producto.objects.get(productoName=data["productoName"])
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Este título ya está en uso.")
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        # Si no existe una tarea con el mismo título, la validación pasa.
        return value

def validate_costo(self, data):
    if data["productoPrice"] <= 0:
       raise ValidationError("Precio no puede ser cero")
    return data
```

View:

```
class ProductoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Producto.objects.all()
serializer_class = ProductoSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
def perform_create(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, se lo agradecería.